# React not rerender component using setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

At the beginning I would like to say that I did not find answer to my question in the other articles so probably it is not a duplicate.

**[Edited]**

My code:

```
export const Structure = () => {
    const [leaf, setLeaf] = useState([]);
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const getTree = async () => {setLeaf(await getTreeService());}

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        var leafClone = [...leaf];

        setLeaf(leafClone);
    }
     useEffect(() => { async function getData() { await getTree(); } getData(); }, []);
     
     return(<div>
                <div>
                    <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
                    <input type="submit" onClick={ onClickHandler} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    {leaf && leaf.length > 0 &&
                        <LeafComponent items={leaf} />}
                </div>
        </div>)
}
```

Question:

**[Edited]**

Should the component be reloaded (currently is not reloading) after pressing "input" because it contains the "setLeaf" method and "leaf" state is pass on **LeafComponent items={leaf}**?
Where is bug in my code?

Comment: everything is ok in my code.I just wanted to bold it in the question instead of in the code and accidentally erased

Comment: @Asaf Aviv so here is my question why my "return"(component) is not re-rending, lol

Comment: we can also forget about SearchChildren method I will simplify the code (still it not working).

Comment: @Asaf aviv look now at this code without SearchChildren method. Still it is not working

Comment: but firstly it takes records from getTreeService so it is not empty.

Comment: console.log shows that from SearchChildren i get proper values. I simplified code for you. Array is not empty!

Answer (score 0):

Your component **is** rendering when submit button clicked.

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-architecture-98zwf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -1):

You need to use e.preventDefault on your input to stop the page from reloading.